# How to handle visualizing massive datasets in D3

Tags: html, d3.js, dom, dataset

I have a dataset with around 230,000 rows, and I'm having a hard time processing the data. I cut out over half of the information, and it still takes around 20 minutes to process into a visualization (constructing the array takes about 20 seconds). The biggest dataset I've dealt with before this (in D3) was only around 210 lines.

Does anyone have any suggestions with how to make dealing with this a little faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If rendering a lot of data all at once is overwhelming, I think it'd be better to split the data into chunks and render the each chunk asynchronously.

For example.

```
function chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
  var R = [];
  for (var i=0,len=arr.length; i<len; i+=chunkSize)
    R.push(arr.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
  return R;
}
var bigData = [...],
  reasonableNumber = 20;

chunk(bigData, reasonableNumber).forEach((splitted) => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => drawWithD3(splitted));
});
```

I hope this will work.